# Installing Ruby on Rails with Fedora 38 is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running Fedora 38 and I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails.  In previous attempts, I just installed Ruby via `dnf` and that didn't work out so well because everything went into `/usr/local/bin`, etc. and I was getting permissions errors not running as sudo.

I removed (I think) all of that and started all over but this time using `rbenv`.

Everything seems to work except when I install Rails, the system cannot find it anywhere.

I run `gem install rails -v 7.1.1` and it shows successful.  But typing "rails" into the terminal results in an error.  Not found.

I tried searching in the shims folder but rails is not there.

[image]

Ruby, gem, bundle, etc. all seem to work just fine.  Just Rails is not found.

Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

It seems that perhaps Rails 7.1.1 is too new.  I just installed 7.1.0 and it works just fine.  I know 7.1.1 just came out, and RubyMine found it earlier today.  But something else is wrong.

I can delete my question if anyone wants but perhaps this could help others with the same issue.